# How to set up Angular Language Service in Neovim

Tags: angular, neovim, language-server-protocol, angular-language-service

My setup at the moment looks like this:

```lua
local cwd = vim.fn.getcwd()
local project_library_path = cwd .. "/node_modules"

local cmd = {
    DATA_PATH .. "/lsp_servers/angularls/node_modules/@angular/language-server/bin/ngserver",
    "--ngProbeLocations",
    project_library_path,
    "--tsProbeLocations",
    project_library_path ,
    "--stdio",
}

require'lspconfig'.angularls.setup{
    cmd = cmd,
    on_new_config = function(new_config, new_root_dir)
        new_config.cmd = cmd
    end
}
```

On `:LspInfo`, I can see that the `cmd` is executable, but somehow it doesn't attach.

I have difficulty to differentiate `@angular/language-server` from `@angular/language-service`...

I am not sure what the `tsProbeLocations` and `ngProbeLocations` do and if my path is correct.

Finally, I red from [Angular Language Service website](https://angular.io/guide/language-service) and there isn't a good guideline for neovim. (except for `coc-angular`, but I don't use coc.)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar setup and the same problem. Make sure that version of the installed language-server matches the major-version of the angular-version used in your project. That solved the issue for me:

```
npm -g uninstall @angular/language-server
npm -g install @angular/language-server@[the latest matching angular-version]
```

With that, the standard  `lua require'lspconfig'.angularls.setup({})` should work without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I used the default `require'lspconfig'.angularls.setup{}` for my lspconfig and also installed [@angular/language-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/language-server/v/13.3.0) as a dev dependency in the angular project and it worked.

With angular language server installed globally with npm and the default lspconfig, I also saw that the cmd is executable with no client attaching to the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
local project_library_path = "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/language-server/"
```